# How to use the theorem of Gauß

Tags: analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3$/{$0$}$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function with $f(x)=\frac{a}{|x|}$ and $a>0$. Show that $f$ is harmonic, and that for every compact 3-dimensional, delimited undermanifold $M$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with a smooth limit and $0$ as an inner point, we have:
>   $$\int_{\partial M}<grad f,v>d \mu_{\partial M}=-4a\Pi$$
>   I already showed, that f is harmonic. We newly introduced this topic, so I'm not sure how to start with this problem. I think I have to use the theorem of Gauß, but could someone explain how to use it? How do you get that exact value with no specific given manifold?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $v$ ? Anyway, if $v(x)$ is the normal vector at $\partial M$ then your integral is $\int_{\partial M} \langle \text{grad}(f), v \rangle d\mu_{\partial M} = \int_M \text{div}(f) d\mu_M$ where $\text{div}{f} = \partial_x f_1 + \partial_y f_2 + \partial_z f_3$. where $f = (f_1,f_2,f_3)$.

Comment: @N.H. not quite. $f$ has a singularity in $0\in M$ This has to be taken into account (and is the key to the exercise)

Comment: Oh sure, you are right. The idea is probably to remove a little ball around $0$, separe the integral in two part and take the limits ?

Comment: Choose a small ball of radius $r$ around $x=0$ and apply the divergence theorem to the region bounded by $\partial M$ and the boundary of the ball. The integral over the bounded region is the integral over the Laplacian, i.e. in your case it vanishes.So you can express your integral as an integral over the boundary of a small ball. There you can calculate $\langle \nabla f,v\rangle$ explicitly. Now let $r$ tend to $0$.

Comment: @N.H. yes, exactly

Comment: (you probably don't even have to let $r\rightarrow 0$, since, without doing the calculation, I'd assume you can calculate the integral explicitly, and it should be independent of $r$)

Comment: @Thomas Ok I understand that the integral over the laplacian vanishes. But why can I express my problem as the integral over the small ball? And why is the solution negative?

Comment: The integral over $M$ minus the ball equals the integral over the boundary of that set. Thats the integral you are already looking at plus the integral over the boundary of the ball. So if you just write down your integral, then $= $ "the remaining terms" you will get the integral over the boundary of the ball. To get the correct sign you'll need to check which normal you are looking at, the inner or the outer one.

Comment: @Thomas So the integral over M is 0 but why is the integral over the small ball -$4a\Pi$? shouldn't it be for the varialbe $B_r(0)$ -$4r^2\Pi$?

Comment: You have to evaluate the integrand ($\langle \nabla \frac{a}{|x|}, v\rangle$ to calculate the integral.

Comment: And what exactly is v? I mean how do you calculate v?

Comment: $v$, quite obviously, has to be be normal to the boundary. See the statement of the divergence theorem.

Comment: @Thomas 
 
So I can choose v myself? for example v=(1,0,0)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $M$ be a smooth $3$-dimensional manifold whose outer boundary (surface) is given by $S_1$ and inner boundary (surface) is a sphere $S_2$ of radius $r>0$ centered at the origin. So the boundary $\partial M$ of $M$ is $S_1\dot\cup S_2$, where $\dot\cup$ is a notation for disjoint union. 
Then 
$$
\begin{align*}
0 &= \int_M 0 \: d\mu_M \\ 
&= \int_M \Delta f \: d\mu_M \\ 
&= \int_M \text{div}(\text{grad}f) d\mu_M \\ 
&= \int_{\partial M} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{\partial M} \\ 
&= \int_{S_1} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{S_1} -\int_{S_2} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{S_2}, \mbox{ where }v \mbox{ is unit normal}. \\ 
\end{align*}
$$
This implies 
$$
\begin{align*}
\int_{S_1} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{S_1} 
&= \int_{S_2} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{S_2} \\ 
&= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} 
\left\langle 
-\frac{a}{r^2}
\left(
\sin \phi\cos \theta,
\sin \phi\sin \theta,
\cos \phi 
\right), \right. \\
&\left. \hspace{4mm} \underbrace{(\sin \phi\cos \theta ,\sin \phi\sin \theta ,\cos \phi )}_{v}
\right\rangle  
r^2 \sin \phi \: d\phi d\theta \\ 
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} -\dfrac{a}{r^2} r^2 \sin \phi \: d\phi d\theta \\ 
&=  \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} -a \sin \phi \: d\phi d\theta \\ 
&=2\pi a \cos\phi\Big|_{0}^{\pi} \\ 
&= 2\pi a (-1-1) \\ 
&= -4\pi a. \\ 
\end{align*}
$$

Now let $r\rightarrow 0$. Then we conclude that 
$$
\int_{\partial M} \langle \text{grad}f, v\rangle d\mu_{\partial M} = -4\pi a. 
$$